# TTY startx runs different GUI than graphical.target

Tags: 20.04, gdm, tty

I recently setup a live Ubuntu 20.04 stick. This is the first time I'm trying Ubuntu, but I am somewhat familiar with the system because I have a RaspberryPi running Raspbian. Everything works great. I am planning on setting it up on a computer to run headless, so I disabled the graphical interface by editing the grub configuration and changing the systemctl default to multi-user.target.

All this works great, however if I use `startx` to start a graphical session, the gui is actually different than auto-booting to gui. For example, there is no `Appearance` option in settings and the Dock is not visible without hitting the start key on the keyboard. The workspace/desktop view is also different. It's as if it is starting a different display manager or something. How do I change how startx boots things?

Again, I'm totally new to this, but would really appreciate the help. I would prefer for both the `startx` and the auto-graphics to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify `GRUB` configuration .

To change the current default target :

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To get the current default target :

```
systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

Now what you can do when you are in text/tty mode , you can start the graphical target by doing this :

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

And you will have the graphical login that will display .

If you need to go back to text/tty mode

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks. I editted the `GRUB` configuration because it didn't seem to boot properly strictly changing the `systemctl` default to `multi-user.target`. Either way, I found out that I can actually run `sudo service gdm3 start` to start the normal graphical interface from the commandline. A little longer than running `startx`, but does what I need.